# Laravel Foreach From Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach, eloquent

Here is the `print_r` of my object;

```
Array
(
[country] => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
            (
                [0] => App\Models\Location Object
                    (
                        [connection:protected] => 
                        [table:protected] => 
                        [primaryKey:protected] => id
                        [perPage:protected] => 15
                        [incrementing] => 1
                        [timestamps] => 1
                        [attributes:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [country] => Scotland
                            )

                        [original:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [country] => Scotland
                            )

                        [relations:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [hidden:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [visible:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [appends:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [fillable:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [guarded:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => *
                            )

                        [dates:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [casts:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [touches:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [observables:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [with:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [morphClass:protected] => 
                        [exists] => 1
                    )

                [1] => App\Models\Location Object
                    (
                        [connection:protected] => 
                        [table:protected] => 
                        [primaryKey:protected] => id
                        [perPage:protected] => 15
                        [incrementing] => 1
                        [timestamps] => 1
                        [attributes:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [country] => England
                            )

                        [original:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [country] => England
                            )

                        [relations:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [hidden:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [visible:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [appends:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [fillable:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [guarded:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => *
                            )

                        [dates:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [casts:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [touches:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [observables:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [with:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [morphClass:protected] => 
                        [exists] => 1
                    )

                [2] => App\Models\Location Object
                    (
                        [connection:protected] => 
                        [table:protected] => 
                        [primaryKey:protected] => id
                        [perPage:protected] => 15
                        [incrementing] => 1
                        [timestamps] => 1
                        [attributes:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [country] => Wales
                            )

                        [original:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [country] => Wales
                            )

                        [relations:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [hidden:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [visible:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [appends:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [fillable:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [guarded:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => *
                            )

                        [dates:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [casts:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [touches:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [observables:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [with:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [morphClass:protected] => 
                        [exists] => 1
                    )

                [3] => App\Models\Location Object
                    (
                        [connection:protected] => 
                        [table:protected] => 
                        [primaryKey:protected] => id
                        [perPage:protected] => 15
                        [incrementing] => 1
                        [timestamps] => 1
                        [attributes:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [country] => 
                            )

                        [original:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [country] => 
                            )

                        [relations:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [hidden:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [visible:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [appends:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [fillable:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [guarded:protected] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => *
                            )

                        [dates:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [casts:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [touches:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [observables:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [with:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [morphClass:protected] => 
                        [exists] => 1
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

I want a foreach loop to print out the three countries in the `country` array - (England, Wales, Scotland).

I have tried loops such as;

```
@foreach ($locations['country'] as $country)
 {{ $country }}
@endforeach
```

I have tried other variations of this but to no avail. What is the correct syntax? Also, can someone explain how I can interpret this so I can better understand foreach with arrays in future? I normally just end up guessing until I get the right result - but for a change I'd like to actually know how to put one together if that makes sense..

I am using Laravel if it helps...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're looping over isn't an array. It's a Laravel Collection. However it behaves like an array so it doesn't really matter. The loop itself actually looks correct. But instead of just outputting `$country` you have to actually access the attribute on `$country` called `country`:

```
@foreach($locations['country'] as $location)
    {{ $location->country }}
@endforeach
```

---

In general a `foreach` loop goes over every item in an array or collection and put's that item into the variable you define after `as`. Maybe [this explanation](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/foreach.php) helps too.

---

As a little extra: Laravel has a nice `lists()` function which builds an array out of an attribute from every model in a collection.

```
$countries = $locations['country']->lists('country');
```

Would result in something like:

```
['England', 'Wales', 'Scotland']
```

And you could then use functions like `implode()` to generate a comma separated list:

```
implode(', ', $countries); // returns 'England, Wales, Scotland'
```